# game does not allow you to win

Tags: c++

I'm writing the code for a game with C++, and when a player is supposed to win, for example all x's on the top row, the game keeps on prompting the next player for their move even when there is supposed to already be a winner. I don't know what's wrong with it, so any help in catching the problem is appreciated! Below is my full code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

enum status{X_WON, O_WON, DRAW, UNFINISHED};

class Board{
    public:
        char boardArray[3][3];
        Board();
        bool makeMove(int, int, char);
        status gameState();
        void print();
    };

Board::Board(){
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
        boardArray[i][j] = '*';
        };
    };
};

bool Board::makeMove(int xIn, int yIn, char player){
    if (boardArray[xIn][yIn] == '*'){
        boardArray[xIn][yIn] = player;
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    };
};

status Board::gameState(){
    status result;

    if(boardArray[0][0] == 'x' && boardArray[0][1] == 'x' && boardArray[0]   [2] == 'x'){
        result = X_WON;
        }; 

    if(boardArray[0][0] == 'o' && boardArray[0][1] == 'o' && boardArray[0][2] == 'o'){
        result = O_WON;
        };  

    if(boardArray[1][0] == 'x' && boardArray[1][1] == 'x' && boardArray[1][2] == 'x'){
        result = X_WON;
        };

    if(boardArray[1][0] == 'o' && boardArray[1][1] == 'o' && boardArray[1][2] == 'o'){
        result = O_WON;
        };   

    if(boardArray[2][0] == 'x' && boardArray[2][1] == 'x' && boardArray[2][2] == 'x'){
        result = X_WON;
        };

    if(boardArray[2][0] == 'o' && boardArray[2][1] == 'o' && boardArray[2][2] == 'o'){
        result = O_WON;
        };     

    if(boardArray[0][0] == 'x' && boardArray[1][0] == 'x' && boardArray[2][0] == 'x'){
        result = X_WON;
        };

    if(boardArray[0][0] == 'o' && boardArray[1][0] == 'o' && boardArray[2][0] == 'o'){
        result = O_WON;
        };    

    if(boardArray[0][1] == 'x' && boardArray[1][1] == 'x' && boardArray[2][1] == 'x'){
        result = X_WON;
        };

    if(boardArray[0][1] == 'o' && boardArray[1][1] == 'o' && boardArray[2][1] == 'o'){
        result = O_WON;
        };     

    if(boardArray[0][2] == 'x' && boardArray[1][2] == 'x' && boardArray[2][2] == 'x'){
        result = X_WON;
        };

    if(boardArray[0][2] == 'o' && boardArray[1][2] == 'o' && boardArray[2][2] == 'o'){
        result = O_WON;
        };

    if(boardArray[0][0] == 'x' && boardArray[1][1] == 'x' && boardArray[2][2] == 'x'){
        result = X_WON;
        };

    if(boardArray[0][0] == 'o' && boardArray[1][1] == 'o' && boardArray[2][2] == 'o'){
        result = O_WON;
        };    

    if(boardArray[0][2] == 'x' && boardArray[1][1] == 'x' && boardArray[2][0] == 'x'){
        result = X_WON;
        };

    if(boardArray[0][2] == 'o' && boardArray[1][1] == 'o' && boardArray[2][0] == 'o'){
        result = O_WON;
        };

    int taken = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            if(boardArray[i][j] != '*'){
                taken++;
                };
            };
        };

    if(taken == 9 && (result != X_WON || result != O_WON)){
        result = DRAW;
        };

    if(taken != 9 && (result != X_WON || result != O_WON || result != DRAW)){
        result = UNFINISHED;
        };     

    return result;        
};


void Board::print(){
    cout << "  " << "0 " << "1 " << "2" << endl;
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    cout << i << " ";
    for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
        cout << boardArray[i][j] << " ";
        };
        cout << endl;
    };    
};

class Ttt {
    private: 
        char player;
    public:
        Board newBoard;
        Ttt();
        void play();
    };

Ttt::Ttt(){
    do{
        cout << "Who should have the first move? x or o?" << endl;
        cin >> player;
        if (player == 'x' || player == 'o'){
            break;
            }else{
                cout << "Not a valid player. Try again." << endl;
                };
        }while(true);
    };    

void Ttt::play(){
    do{        
        int xcoord, ycoord;

        do{
            cout << "Player " << player << " , please enter your move. Example: 0 [enter] 0 (numbers from 0 - 2)" << endl;
            cin >> xcoord >> ycoord;

            if(newBoard.makeMove(xcoord, ycoord, player) == false){
                cout << "That move is not valid. Try again." << endl;
                }else{
                    break;
                    };

            }while(true);

        newBoard.makeMove(xcoord, ycoord, player);

        newBoard.print();

        if(player == 'x'){
            player = 'o';
            }else{
                player = 'x';
                };

        if(newBoard.gameState() == X_WON){
            cout << "Player X is the winner!" << endl;
            break;
            };

        if(newBoard.gameState() == O_WON){
            cout << "Player O is the winner!" << endl;
            break;
            };    

        if(newBoard.gameState() == DRAW){
            cout << "Draw!" << endl;
            break;
            };        
        }while(true); 
    };    

int main(){
    Ttt newgame;
    newgame.play();
}
```

Comment: Please have a look at how to provide a [mcve] - we want questions to be as clear and brief as possible so they can help other people. As it stands, your provided code contains a great deal of irrelevant information that people with your problem and people seeking to solve your problem will both have to wade through.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: "Tic Tac Toe game does not allow you to win" this is typical of Tic Tac Toe. If you are familiar with [the classics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WarGames), then you should already know that "The only winning move is not to play."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test

```
(result != X_WON || result != O_WON || result != DRAW)
```

is always true, since result can't be equal to all 3 values.
`result` should be initialised to `UNFINISHED` and the test changed to:

```
(taken != 9 && result == UNFINISHED)
```